# Display page of custom posts?

Tags: loop, categories, archive-template

I have a custom post type, "design_asset".

I am displaying them on a page template, with the loop

```
<?php
rewind_posts();
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'design_asset', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'  );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <p class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php    endwhile;   ?>
```

Also on this page, I am listing the categories with `wp_list_categories`

When you click a category in this list, it goes to archive.php and displays the category there, [thanks to this post's reply](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155549/wp-list-categories-and-custom-post-types), e.g.`/category/components/`

I don't fully understand why Wordpress uses `archive.php` instead of `category.php`, but let's go with it for now.

Now, I am trying to re-purpose this loop on `archive.php`. I moved it into `loop-assetThumbs.php` and call it with `<?php get_template_part('loop', 'assetThumbs'); ?>`

Of course, it calls ALL of the posts or the post type, I can't figure out how to display only the "active" category in the URL, `/category/components/`

How do I modify the loop to do this?  Or is there a better way to display categories of custom post types via `wp_list_categories`?

Note: I'm also not sure why it's showing 2 empty iterations of the loop here.

[image]

Comment: Seems like categories is been treated as taxonomy terms, which will explain why archive.php is used instead of category.php. I also believe then that you don't have a taxonomy.php template then, otherwise wordpress would have used that and not archive.php

Comment: Nope.  I created taxonomy.php, and it still uses archive.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the exact code that you've mentioned. [`pre_get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is a bastard if you don't use it correctly.

With any archive type conditions used in `pre_get_posts`, it will affect both front end and back end. This include archives pages, category and taxonomy pages, tag pages and author pages. You'll need to do a check that you only run `pre_get_posts` on the front end (use `!is_admin()`).

One other important thing you'll need to do is to run `pre_get_posts` only on the main query. Because `pre_get_posts` runs first before the main query and `WP_Query` and modify the query variables, both the main query and any custom queries using `WP_Query` will be affected. (Use `is_main_query()`)

So you will need to modify the code in question to this to add the `!is_admin` check

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
            'post', 'your-custom-post-type-here'
));
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

I hope this helps. If not, let me know.

**EDIT**

Steve, before you make these changes I've proposed, first check [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155736/31545) on your other question. But please keep the points in mind in this answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks Pieter.  As I said there, I have mostly worked with custom Page templates but am new to the other template loops and related functions.

Comment: I would recommend to have a read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to get a better understanding of theme development. Just glad I could help. Please accept this answer as well so this can also go as solved, unless you still need some assistance